# Use of constants in sqlite versioning

Tags: android, sqlite

We found a lot of tutorial on sqlite using constants to manage request in methods of sqlite file... But it is a good way ? Immagine we rename three times columns of a database we will have three times the same constant with a different name.

So what is the best practice ? For myself, I write the versioning like that:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if (oldVersion < 4) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + "demandes" + " RENAME TO demandes2");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "demandes" + "(" + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "xmlSendLead" + " TEXT," + "statutEnvoieSendLead" + " INTEGER," + "dateEnvoieSendLead" + " DATETIME," + "contactWebId" + " INTEGER," + "xmlSimulation" + " TEXT," + "statutEnvoieSimulation" + " INTEGER," + "dateEnvoieSimulation" + " DATETIME" + ")");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "demandes" + " (" + "id" + "," + "xmlSendLead" + "," + "statutEnvoieSendLead" + "," + "dateEnvoieSendLead" + ")" + " SELECT id, xml, statutEnvoie, dateEnvoie" + " FROM demandes2;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE demandes2");
        System.out.println("v4 parsed");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 5) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "leads" + "(" + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "xmlSendLead" + " TEXT," + "statutSendLead" + " INTEGER," + "dateSendLead" + " DATETIME," + "contactWebId" + " INTEGER," + "xmlSimulation" + " TEXT," + "statutSendSimulation" + " INTEGER," + "dateSendSimulation" + " DATETIME" + ")");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "leads" + " (" + "id" + "," + "xmlSendLead" + "," + "statutSendLead" + "," + "dateSendLead" + "contactWebId" + "," + "xmlSimulation" + "," + "statutSendSimulation" + "," + "dateSendSimulation" + ")" + " SELECT id, xml, statutEnvoie, dateEnvoie" + " FROM demandes2;");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "leads" + "(" + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "prepaymentPenaltyPercentage" + " REAL," + "notaryFeeGrid" + " INTEGER," + "immoRatePercentage" + " REAL," + "immoMinMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "immoMaxMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "fileFeePercentage" + " REAL," + "date" + " DATETIME," + "consoRatePercentage" + " REAL," + "consoMinMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "consoMaxMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "bankFeePercentage" + " REAL)");
    }
}
```

So here I will never do mistakes between names... for the other methods I use constants. What do you think about ?

Other methods:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "solutis.db";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

private static final String TABLE_LEADS = "leads";
private static final String KEY_XML_SENDLEAD = "xmlSendLead";
private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD = "statutEnvoieSendLead";
private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD = "dateEnvoieSendLead";
private static final String KEY_CONTACTWEBID = "contactWebId";
private static final String KEY_XML_SIMULATION = "xmlSimulation";
private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SIMULATION = "statutEnvoieSimulation";
private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE_SIMULATION = "dateEnvoieSimulation";

private static final String TABLE_SIMULATIONPARAMS = "simulationParams";
private static final String KEY_BANKFEEPERCENTAGE = "bankFeePercentage";
private static final String KEY_CONSOMAXMONTHLY = "consoMaxMonthly";
private static final String KEY_CONSOMINMONTHLY = "consoMinMonthly";
private static final String KEY_CONSORATEPERCENTAGE = "consoRatePercentage";
private static final String KEY_FILEFEEPERCENTAGE = "fileFeePercentage";
private static final String KEY_IMMOMAXMONTHLY = "immoMaxMonthly";
private static final String KEY_IMMOMINMONTHLY = "immoMinMonthly";
private static final String KEY_IMMORATEPERCENTAGE = "immoRatePercentage";
private static final String KEY_PREPAYMENTPENALTYPERCENTAGE = "prepaymentPenaltyPercentage";
private static final String KEY_NOTARYFEEGRID = "notaryFeeGrid";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LEADS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_XML_SENDLEAD + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD + " DATETIME," + KEY_CONTACTWEBID + " INTEGER," + KEY_XML_SIMULATION + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SIMULATION + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE_SIMULATION + " DATETIME" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE);
    /*
    String CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LEADS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_XML_SENDLEAD + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD + " DATETIME" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE);
    */
}


public Demande addDemande(Demande demande) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_XML_SENDLEAD, demande.getXmlSendLead());
    values.put(KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SENDLEAD, demande.getStatutEnvoieSendLead());
    values.put(KEY_DATEENVOIE_SENDLEAD, demande.getDateEnvoieSendLead());
    values.put(KEY_CONTACTWEBID, demande.getContactWebId());
    values.put(KEY_XML_SIMULATION, demande.getXmlSimulation());
    values.put(KEY_STATUTENVOIE_SIMULATION, demande.getStatutEnvoieSimulation());
    values.put(KEY_DATEENVOIE_SIMULATION, demande.getDateEnvoieSimulation());
    //long test = db.insert(TABLE_LEADS, null, values);
    //int test2 = (int) test;
    //demande.setID(test2);
    long insert = db.insert(TABLE_LEADS, null, values);
    int insertDemande = (int) insert;
    demande.setId(insertDemande);
    db.close();
    return demande;
}
```

Comment: `variable` Using proper terminology is pretty crucial in IT. Did you mean `column` here? Also your `execSQL()` queries looks nonsense. Why you concatenate strings, instead of having just one?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sorry for the string concatenation I was using variables before, but when I whange the column name a lot of times, I get so much variables to manage

Comment: How many columns you got in table? 10? 20? Still better to use constants instead of typing column names by hand as the latter will hit you with chasing-stupid-typo issue sooner than later.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski It's look pretty difficult to manage for me, okay now it's a little database, but how do a big apps with a lot of data ??

Comment: That depeneds. Some may use ORM or have the DB layer isolated other way by having some sort of Model class. That's too big subject to discuss. Google on that as this is quite popular subject

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What can I tape ? "Big database in android" ?

Comment: @CL. Look my edit please

Comment: @CL. Sorry I do every times the same mistake... yes i'm talking about constants

Comment: an option may be to define constants with version only for migration, like `KEY_ID_V4 = "old_column_name"` ... but otherwise using in migration method hard-coded strings with old names, except the latest names (which can use constants) sounds OK-ish to me. Then again I very rarely need to rename database column, and usually I try hard to avoid such situation, if the new column has considerably different data, I just add it and keep the old one available any way, phasing it out slowly over several versions. If it's just typo/clarification rename, then it's OK as you do it, that should be rare.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the table/column names directly into the SQL statements, you increase the risk that you misspell it somewhere, and that the app will blow up later.
If you use constants instead, the compiler will complain about any typos.

So in general, you should always use the constants.

However, even using constants does not protect against accidentally using the wrong one.
So you still have to test all your code.

If you think that the actual table/column names are more readable than TABLE_THIS and KEY_THAT, and if you are confident that your tests will catch all mistakes, then you could decide not to use the constants. And whether that decision will have been a good idea is something that you will have to find out yourself.